# How to capitalize only first letter in filename using tr or mv on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Using terminal I need to write a command with `mv`/`tr`/`find` to:

1. Find files with names that start with `a`, `o` or `e`: `[a,o,e]*`.
2. Change those filenames first letters from lower to capital using `tr` or `mv`.

Everything has to be in one command not script. I've tried something like this:

```
find -name "[a,o,e]*" -exec {} mv [a,o,e]* [A,O,E]* \;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Bash can do that to the [contents of a variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). For example, look at what `for name in [aoe]* ; do echo "$name" "${name^[aoe]}" ; done` outputs, if the current directory has files that begin with one of those three letters.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Make some test files using `touch` first. Then try your `find` without `-exec` till you get the wildcards right for selecting the files correctly. Then carry on...

Comment: So find without exec actually shows what i want: find -name "[a,o,e]*", i mean these are files starting from letters a or o or e, now how to repleace them to [A,O,E]* :/

Comment: I know this is not just one command but one command doing this may be complex to understand. Try this: `for f in $(find . -name "*" -type f|sed "s/^.\///"); do echo "- File is: $f"; f1stc=$(echo ${f::1}|tr [a-z] [A-Z]); fallbut1stc=$(echo ${f:1}); echo "   - File's 1st char is: $f1stc and rest characters are: $fallbut1stc"; echo; nf="${f1stc}${fallbut1stc}"; mv $f ${nf} 2>/dev/null || true; echo "  - File after mv operation now is: ${nf}"; echo; done`

Comment: Try `touch ",oops"` and run `find` again.

Comment: Do you know about parameter expansion? https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html 
There is nice solution exactly to your need.

Comment: Can you use something else than `tr`, like `sed -r 's/(.)(.*)/mv "\1\2" "\U\1\E\2"/' <<< "examleFileName" `

Comment: I have to do this as simple as possible and as short as possible and i can't use sed :/ only find or grep or ls, and mv or tr

Comment: "as simple as possible" and "only use tools x,y,z" are contradictory requirements.

Comment: With just GNU find, bash, and mv, the simplest that does this to a full subtree I can come up with is `find -name '[oae]*' -printf '%h\0%f\0' | bash -c 'while read -d "" dir ; do read -d "" name ; echo mv -vi "$dir/$name" "$dir/${name^[aoe]}" ; done'` without the `echo` in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sample with some of my files starting with letters `p` and `g`:

```
$ find . -name '[pg]*.py'
./pycurl-example.py
./pymusic.py
./gtkmenu.py
```

You could use something like bellow, but unfortunatelly will not stop on the first occurence - it will translate all letters found:

```
$ find . -name '[pg]*.py' |tr '[pg]' '[PG]'
./Pycurl-examPle.Py
./Pymusic.py
./Gtkmenu.Py
```

Sinc `tr` has not an option to stop at first occurence like sed, you can make a trick like this:

```
$ find . -name '[pg]*.py' -exec bash -c 'echo -n "${0:2:1}"|tr 'pg' 'PG' && echo "${0:3}"' {} \;
Pycurl-example.py
Pymusic.py
Gtkmenu.py
```

**Or even simplier without `tr` but with pure bash (idea from @Nominal Animal comment)**

```
$ find . -name '[pg]*.py' -exec bash -c 'fn="${0:2}";echo "${fn^}"' {} \;
Pycurl-example.py
Pymusic.py
Gtkmenu.py
```

Or if your purpose is to do a real rename:

```
$ find . -name '[p]*c.py' -exec bash -c 'fn="${0:2}";mv -v "${fn}" "${fn^}"' {} \;
renamed 'pymusic.py' -> 'Pymusic.py'
```

**And a more sophisticated rename that will work with any path:**

```
$ find . -name 'g*.sh' -exec bash -c 'pn="${0%/*}";fn="${0##*/}";mv -v $0 ${pn}/${fn^}' {} \;
renamed './kalitools/Bluelog/scripts/gen_oui.sh' -> './kalitools/Bluelog/scripts/Gen_oui.sh'
renamed './greptest.sh' -> './Greptest.sh'
```

Comment: Your solution works fine :) I also found sth like this:
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i^}"; done

And it's actually working, but on all files, so i need to convert it to sth like:
for i in `find -name [aoe]*`; do mv "$i" "${i^}"; done
but mv says: its the same file :/

Comment: @szeejdi This message `same file` may mean that somehow your files have been already renamed in one of your trials... i.e in your first attempt using `for i in *`

Comment: @szeejdi no problem. Just remember that the opposite of `${i^}` is the `${i,}`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '[aoe]*' -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(echo "$1"|sed -E "s,(.*/)(.),\1\u\2,")"' _ {} ';'
```

Remove the first "echo" if it looks like it's going to do what you want.

In my tmp dir with all kinds of crap in it, some of the output is:

```
mv ./a b c ./A b c
mv ./a.awk ./A.awk
mv ./a.prop ./A.prop
mv ./a1234 ./A1234
mv ./event.logger ./Event.logger
mv ./example.txt ./Example.txt
mv ./link/a ./link/A
mv ./link/a~ ./link/A~
mv ./old.csv ./Old.csv
mv ./rename/one-dash ./rename/One-dash
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 for f in `find . -name "*" -type f|sed "s/^.\///"`; do f1stc=$(echo ${f::1}|tr [a-z] [A-Z]); fallbut1stc=$(echo ${f:1}); nf="${f1stc}${fallbut1stc}"; mv $f ${nf} 2>/dev/null || true; done
```